# search for a string and after getting result cut that word and store result in variable

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, grep

I Have a file name abc.lst i ahve stored that in a variable it contain 3 words string among them i want to grep second word and in that i want to cut the word from expdp to .dmp and store that into variable

**example:-**

```
REFLIST_OP=/tmp/abc.lst 
cat $REFLIST_OP      
34 /data/abc/GOon/expdp_TEST_P119_*_18112017.dmp       12-JAN-18 04.27.00 AM
```

**Desired Output:-**

```
expdp_TEST_P119_*_18112017.dmp
```

**I Have tried below command :-**

```
     FULL_DMP_NAME=`cat $REFLIST_OP|grep /orabackup|awk '{print $2}'`

     echo $FULL_DMP_NAME

    /data/abc/GOon/expdp_TEST_P119_*_18112017.dmp
```

Comment: The real bug here is not quoting the argument to `echo`.  You want double quotes around the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
REFLIST_OP=/tmp/abc.lst
awk '{n=split($2,arr,/\//); print arr[n]}' "$REFLIST_OP"
```

Test Results:

```
$ REFLIST_OP=/tmp/abc.lst
$ cat "$REFLIST_OP"
34 /data/abc/GOon/expdp_TEST_P119_*_18112017.dmp       12-JAN-18 04.27.00 AM
$ awk '{n=split($2,arr,/\//); print arr[n]}' "$REFLIST_OP" 
expdp_TEST_P119_*_18112017.dmp
```

To save in variable

```
myvar=$( awk '{n=split($2,arr,/\//); print arr[n]}' "$REFLIST_OP" )
```

Comment: Thanks mate it is what i want

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk -F'/| ' '{print $6}'   Input_file
```

OR

```
awk -F'/| ' '{print $6}' "$REFLIST_OP"
```

***Explanation:*** Simply making space and `/` as a field separator(as per your shown Input_file) and then printing 6th field of the line which is required by OP.
To see the field number and field's value you could use following command too:

```
awk -F'/| ' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print i,$i}}' "$REFLIST_OP"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed with one of these regex

`sed -e 's/.*\/\([^[:space:]]*\).*/\1/' abc.lst` capture non space characters after `/`, printing only the captured part.

`sed -re 's|.*/([^[:space:]]*).*|\1|' abc.lst` Same as above, but using different separator, thus  avoiding to escape the `/`. `-r` to use unescaped `(`

`sed -e 's|.*/||' -e 's|[[:space:]].*||' abc.lst` in two steps, remove up to last `/`, remove from space to end. (May be easiest to read/understand)

`myvar=$(<abc.lst); myvar=${myvar##*/};  myvar=${myvar%% *}; echo $myvar` 
If you want to avoid external command (`sed`)